# Dynamically grabbing input / select values without direct targeting - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have a set of list items that hold input and select boxes inside of them. Im attempting to loop through the list items, grab the values inside of them then run a function based on those figures with the result pushing into an array. Im struggling to get the structure right of my click function unfortunately.

**Calculation Function**

```
function calculateSum(power, amountItem, usage) {
    var finalSum;

    if (power && amountItem && usage != null) {
        finalSum = (power * amountItem * usage)/1000;
    } else {
        console.log('Parameters not passed into calculateSum function');
    }
    return finalSum;
};
```

**Click Function - The part where I'm struggling.**

```
   calculationsArray = [];
    $('#calculate-this').on('click', function(){
          $('#calculation-options li').each( function() {
                 var power = $('.wattage select').val();
                 var amount = $('.quantity-output').val();
                 var usage = $('.usage select').val();
                 var calculationResult = calculateSum(power, amount,usage);
                 console.log(calculationResult);
                 calculationsArray.push(calculationResult);
           });
    });
```

**Example HTML Li Structure**

```
<ul id="calculation-options">           
<li id="item-1">
    <div>
        <img data-name="item-1" id="item-1" src="img/item1.png" alt="Begin Process"/>
    </div>                          
        <div class="controls-wrapper">
            <div class="controls-wrapper-inner">
              <input name="quantity" class="quantity-output quantity-value-1" value="5">
                  <div class="controls-wrapper-selector">
                    <a data-id="1" class="minus">-</a>
                    <a data-id="1" class="plus">+</a>
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="power">
            <select>
              <option selected="selected" value="POWER">Power</option>  
              <option value="70">70w</option>
              <option value="100">100w</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="Usage">
            <select>
              <option selected="selected" value="usage">Usage</option>  
              <option value="1">1 Hours</option>
              <option value="2">2 Hours</option>
            </select>
        </div>
</li>
<li id="item-2">
    <div>
        <img data-name="item-2" id="item-2" src="img/item2.png" alt="Begin Process"/>
    </div>                          
        <div class="controls-wrapper">
            <div class="controls-wrapper-inner">
              <input name="quantity" class="quantity-output quantity-value-1" value="5">
                  <div class="controls-wrapper-selector">
                    <a data-id="1" class="minus">-</a>
                    <a data-id="1" class="plus">+</a>
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="power">
            <select>
              <option selected="selected" value="POWER">Power</option>  
              <option value="70">70w</option>
              <option value="100">100w</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="Usage">
            <select>
              <option selected="selected" value="usage">Usage</option>  
              <option value="1">1 Hours</option>
              <option value="2">2 Hours</option>
            </select>
        </div>
</li>
</ul>
<a id="calculate-this">Calculate This!</a>
```

Any direction would be great!

D

Comment: Are you missing some of the code? you dont have a button in the html, and 3 variables are missing values altogether

Comment: Thanks for your comment code - apologies, I've just added these in, unfortunately the code I missed out is the part I'm struggling with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQueryElement.each( ... )` takes a function reference with 2 parameters, the first being an index and the second being an element. Use that element to your advantage.

```
$('#calculation-options li').each( function( i, elem ) {
  console.log( $(elem).find( 'option:selected' ) );
} );
```

Comment: Seems like the perfect way to get the information - thanks!